# Trigger onsubmit without submit-button

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, submit, onsubmit

I'm stuck, trying to submit my form using the submit function (`formElement.submit()`).

Well, actually It do send the form-input-values to the backend, but I'm trying to prevent it and adding ajax in between.

Jade/pug

```
form#score-form(method="POST" action="/leaderboard")
    input#submit-score(type="hidden" value="" name="submitscore")
    //value is fetched from JS
```

JS

```
scoreForm.submit();
scoreForm.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    //Nothing here will be invoked
});
```

However, when using a submit button, it works as intended

```
form#score-form(method="POST" action="/leaderboard")
    input#submit-score(type="hidden" value="" name="submitscore")
    button(type="submit")

scoreForm.submit();
scoreForm.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    console.log("works"); //logs works
});
```

Everything works fine except the fact that it seems that .submit() doesn't invoke onsubmit. Is there any workaround (preferably with vanilla js), to give the program a hint that the form is submitted, even with .submit()?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're registering event listener before calling the event?

Comment: Ah, actually I'm not. That and the .click() simulation works perfectly, thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the listener before you actually submit:

```
scoreForm.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    console.log("works"); //logs works
});
scoreForm.submit();
```

Otherwise the event will have fired before you have a listener set up

**Edit:** it seems I misread what you were asking. The answer you're looking for is that `submit()` will not fire the listener. you can simulate it by programatically clicking on the button with `click()`. [Here is a good](http://codetheory.in/javascript-fire-onsubmit-by-calling-form-submit/) explanation of this behaviour. try:

```
scoreForm.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').click()
```

Comment: Yepp, that's it! Thanks!

Comment: `.click()` is `obsolete` according to `MDN` https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click