# React form workaround to fire submit event when form.submit() is executed

Tags: reactjs, form-submit

I have a simple React login component like this:

```
function Login() {

const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

function handleSubmit(event){
    // do stuff
}

if(loggedIn)
    return <Afterlogin />;
return (
    <div className="login">
        <form id="login" className="login__container" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
                id="username"
                type="text"
                name="username"
                className="login__textBox"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="name"
            />
            <input
                id="password"
                type="password"
                name="password"
                className="login__textBox"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="password"
            />
            <button
                className="login__btn"
                type='submit'
            >
                login
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
);
```

This works fine, however this login is used by some 3rd party tool which uses an auto login script.

This script apparently calls the forms `submit()` method. Unfortunately this does not work so I opened the login site and the developer console to reproduce the issue.

`document.getElementById('login').submit()` returns `undefined`.

After some researching I found out that this an [expected behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit).

> No submit event is raised. In particular, the form's onsubmit event handler is not run.

So my questions is, how do I have to change my component so that the auto login script works? Sadly I can not change the auto login script.

Comment: We have two point here: the `undefined` value and the script. The `undefined` value it is normal, the `submit()` method does not return a value. About the second point, not sure so I will not mark as a duplicate, but maybe this can help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42402560/trigger-onsubmit-without-submit-button

Comment: thanks, this describes the same issue however the solution in the answer is using the 
`click()` method however, as I said, I can not change the autologin script.